# What is the nature and character of fire?

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

What is fire? Is it a material or energy or something else? Please explain it to me. My friend asked me this. I am stuck with this problem.

Comment: See [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/what-are-the-chemical-reactions-behind-fire) for an excellent overview of the chemistry of fire from user Ben Norris and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITpDrdtGAmo) for some insights from the great Feynman.

Comment: I think you should read the [question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/what-are-the-chemical-reactions-behind-fire) linked by Nicolau if this don't fulfill your thirst of knowledge try to be more specific... ;-)

Comment: @Neto why not to post this comments as an answer? So the question will be no longer appear as an unanswered question.